# git remote prune does not delete remote branches

Tags: git

`git branch -r` shows a bunch of branches I deleted from another computer:

```
-bash-4.1$ git branch -r
origin/access-qa
origin/add-search-efforts
origin/align-buttons
origin/enable-features
origin/fix-code-coverage
origin/master
origin/qa
origin/search-effort-qa
origin/specs-run-once-test
```

`ls-remote` shows no such branches:

```
bash-4.1$ git ls-remote origin
5a14d91b7b257f194a82e4d51a4b7e9523969c5a    HEAD
ac5962d0b35910494ad1079dc050e7ed605cb52b    refs/heads/align-buttons
5a14d91b7b257f394a82e4d51a4b7e9523969c5a    refs/heads/master
d8bc750f9a763cf7b74a546e6aee6b1764b3a65b    refs/heads/search-effort-qa
d20c2691afead974156d2d47fd7cd7dc3d40870e    refs/pull/1/head
3648c9e85be2dffd9175e3a39ab6b19761d111e1    refs/pull/1/merge
326476732e6dc41d87c3fd556fc2f5f272a58236    refs/pull/2/head
5e55eb5c4c76667dd2369cf7830b30c0e256b501    refs/pull/2/merge
da4731db499709c6f96010adb583eb23898ec91d    refs/pull/3/head
```

I've tried to get rid of them:

```
git remote prune origin
git fetch origin --prune
git remote update -p
git prune
git fsck
git gc
git gc --prune=now
```

But `git branch -r` still shows the branches.

Note this is a Jenkins workspace (each with repo from `git clone`).  I have 5 other workspaces.  In one workspace, `git remote prune origin` worked perfectly.

I'm starting to think my repo is corrupt.  Removing the remote and re-adding successfully removes the remote references, but I'd have assumed that there is a better way.

Comment: What is the `git config remote.origin.fetch` in that repo?

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem: `git config remote.origin.fetch` was blank, whereas in my other workspaces it was set correctly.  I've updated `remote.origin.fetch` and a `git fetch origin --prune` clears out the remote branches.

Comment: @Irineau, did you want to post an answer?  Alternatively I can post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior of Git is strange. It could be explained by a wrong value of `git config remote.origin.fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but the best way to remove a branch from git is:

```
git branch -D branchName (your branch will be removed from your local)
git push origin :branchName (your branch will be removed in the repository)
```

Hope this hepls

Comment: Hi jbartolome, thank you for your answer.  I've deleted branches from my local repo and remote repo using techniques you outlined, however I'm still seeing these branches appear in from another computer and am unable to remove them.

Comment: From the other computer just type 'git fetch'. These branches should disappear.